# Install Elastic Search for Magento 2.4 on Cpanel Hosting

Tags: elasticsearch, terminal, hosting, cpanel, magento2

I'm using aspnix hosting. I have installed jdk and elastic search from terminal. However when i try to run or check status of elasticsearch via curl its saying connection refused

```
curl: (7) Failed connect to srikrishnasilks.com:9200; Connection refused
```

Please help as im unable to install magento  2.4 without this installed

Comment: contact your sever support

Comment: @RizwanKhan Contacted them. They are saying this is related to developer. They cant help...so im confused.

Comment: you have elasticsearch installed on your server?

Comment: make sure to add elasticsearch path as localhost:9200

Answer (score 0):

In Latest Magento 2.4, Elasticsearch installation must be required for catalog search. You need to set up the first Elasticsearch before Magento 2.4 installation. also, Elasticsearch required JDK(Java Development Kit) before the installation.

For more information, You need to check [How to install ElasticSearch](https://rb.gy/9jjhkq)